# I want to know how to cite some code block in comments to a question

Tags: support

I want to know how to cite some code block in comments to a question. 
Is this not acceptable? If acceptable, how to do that?

Comment: The only way to do that is to use these backticks: ` `for this inline code style`. There is no way to have entire blocks in comments, no.

Comment: Why do you want to do that anyway? Just link to the post.

Comment: I am a newcomer here. How to link ..where can I find the link

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer ?

Comment: (also use @RAGHHURAAMM to reply to users)

Comment: How to create a link: try clicking that "help" link next to the comment box. Feel free to experiment getting it to work right here in the comments ;)

Comment: By cite, do you mean create a link to a specific code block in a question? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Block in question.

Comment: @RAGHHURAAMM I think that you may have meant to use the word "possible" instead of "acceptable." Asking if something is acceptable is usually a question for something that you are capable of doing, but are unsure if it's something that is good to do or not. Asking if something is possible is a question to see if there exists some way to do what you suggest. If that is what you are asking, I suggest you change both words "acceptable" to "possible," as that will make your question more clear.

Comment: Actually I meant it to be 'acceptable' only, but still don't know how to do it because I am a newcomer to this site. I should know what are the ethics followed at this site before I do it, even after knowing how to do it. That's it. no issues.

Comment: while commenting on some code mentioned in the question, I may need to insert some code snippet shown in the question so that the person who made the question can easily refer back. But not the entire long code block. Just a small bit of code. Ok, anyway that can be don using backticks as already answered above by Pekka .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments are barebones and do not enjoy the full benefit of formatting that questions and answers do.  Therefore, you cannot "cite" a block of code in comments simply by copying and pasting said block into your comment.

Now, given that you have less than 50 reputation right now, the motivation for you wanting to do this is dubious.  It may be the case that instead of citing the code, you want to reply to the person who posted it (which you can without the 50 rep, if and only if it is your question).   You only need to leave a comment on their answer in that case.